# Traffic Manager - This value is neither an IP address nor a fully qualified domain name (FQDN)

Tags: azure-traffic-manager

I don't know where should I post this...
So the issue is cannot add target in External endpoint if there is "one word only" between "."
Example:
example.com - working
abc.example.com - working
a.abc.example.com - working
abc.a.example.com - is not working
guest.v.example.com - is not working

The error message is "This value is neither an IP address nor a fully qualified domain name (FQDN)."
If Microsoft staff see this, please fix this. I didn't pay for open case...

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/

Comment: Hi Niklas, I am using Azure for Student only. The link you've provided need to pay to MS...

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same error and such FQDN `abc.a.example.com` can not be added in External endpoint.

[image]

From this [Azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/11254839-traffic-manager-support-for-external-endpoints-tha#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D), you could add IP address there in this case.

> **Traffic Manager support for external endpoints that are IP addresses
> instead of FQDN is available.**

Comment: Even provided another workaround but I won't take this as I am using DDNS for domain...

Comment: I suggesting raise a ticket to MS. As far as I know it looks like a limitation for external endpoint.

Comment: But I don't have any support plan to raise ticket in Azure...